# Django: How can I create a User view that allows a User to amend or delete their existing bookings?

Tags: django, django-views

I am developing a restaurant booking service using Django. I want to create a view for an authenticated user to view only their existing bookings. In the same view, I would also like them to be able to amend and/or deleted any of their bookings.

So far I have managed to get the code right for the authenticated user to only see their bookings but at this point, they cannot do anything with it.

**models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):

   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   group_size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   date = models.DateField(blank=False)
   start_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
   end_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
   comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
   created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.table}. Booked by {self.user} for {self.group_size} people, for the {self.date} at {self.start_time}. Status {self.approved}'
```

**views.py**

```
class BookingList(TemplateView):

   template_name = 'user_booking.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      return super().get_context_data(bookings=self.request.user.booking_set.all(), **kwargs)
```

**html_template**

```
{% for booking in user.booking_set.all %}
<h2>{{ booking }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

**output**

```
Table 4, WINDOW. Capacity 4 guests. Booked by admin for 4 people, for the 2022-04-30 at 18:00:00. Status True Table 1, OUTSIDE. 
Capacity 2 guests. Booked by admin for 2 people, for the 2022-04-30 at 12:00:00. Status False
```

Comment: You could simply add a button near each booking to allows the user to delete it.

Comment: Hi RedWheelbarrow, thank you for your response. Can I ask you to elaborate on this a little more please? I am a newbie to coding so apologies for not being able to read into your response further. Are you suggesting I can simply add buttons in the html template?

Comment: Hi I have made a minimal example in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add two links near each booking to allow the user to update/delete them.

Change your `views.py`:

```py
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView

class BookingList(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'user_booking.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['bookings'] = self.request.user.booking_set.all()
      return context

class BookingAmend(UpdateView):
   model = Booking
   template_name = 'amend_booking.html'
   fields = ['table', 'group_size', 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'comment']  # Insert the fields that are editable by the user (change it as your need)
   success_url ='/'  # Insert the path used to open BookingList
   
   def get_queryset(self):
      return self.request.user.booking_set.all()

class BookingDelete(DeleteView):
   model = Booking
   template_name = 'delete_booking.html'
   success_url ='/'  # Insert the path used to open BookingList

   def get_queryset(self):
      return self.request.user.booking_set.all()
```

Edit your `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
   # Other url patterns
   path('<pk>/amend/', BookingAmend.as_view(), name='booking_amend'),
   path('<pk>/delete/', BookingDelete.as_view(), name='booking_delete'),
]
```

Add this template (name it `amend_booking.html`):

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Add this template (name it `delete_booking.html`):

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<p>Are you sure you want to delete the booking?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Edit your `user_booking.html` template:

```html
{% for booking in bookings %}
<h2>{{ booking }}</h2> <a href="{% url 'booking_amend' pk=booking.pk %}">amend</a> <a href="{% url 'booking_delete' pk=booking.pk %}">delete</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you should use some css to make it more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: Thats a brilliant example, Thank you so much... I will try this out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Wow...amazing...this has worked brilliantly!!! Thank you so much for your support. But there is one functionality still missing from my original problem statement above... That is, How can we allow the User to amend an existing booking? Thanks again for this...it is really appreciated and am learning a lot.

Comment: @Rp_Web Excuse me but english is not my language, with "amend"you intend "edit" or "approve"?

Comment: No problem at all. By amend I mean to edit an existing booking. No need for approving as this will be part of the admin function which is already in place. Just edit :)

Comment: @Rp_Web Ok, I have edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks again RedWheelbarrow, but there seems to be something missing here, the amend feature is visible which is great but when I click "amend" it doesn't go anywhere.. I would expect it to take me back to the "bookingform" view with my booking details visible for me to amend right?

Comment: @Rp_Web When you click "amend" in `user_booking.html` it does not go anywhere (did you get any error)? Instead if the problem is that after you finish amend the booking in `amend_booking.html` it does not go anywhere, you need to change the success_url of `BookingAmend` to match the path of  `BookingList` (you don't provide your urls.py so I don't know which path is used). Please describe more the situation

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path("booking/", views.BookingFormView.as_view(), name="bookingform"),
    path("menu/", views.Menu.as_view(), name="menu"),
    path("contacts/", views.ContactFormView.as_view(), name="contacts"),
    path("booking_list/", views.BookingList.as_view(), name="user_booking"),
    path("<pk>/amend/", BookingAmend.as_view(), name="booking_amend"),
    path("<pk>/delete/", BookingDelete.as_view(), name="booking_delete"),
]

Comment: class BookingAmend(UpdateView):
    model = Booking
    template_name = 'amend_booking.html'
    fields = ['table', 'group_size', 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'comment']  # Insert the fields that are editable by the user (change it as your need)
    success_url = '/restaurant/booking_list/'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.booking_set.all()

Comment: class BookingDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Booking
    template_name = 'delete_booking.html'
    success_url = '/restaurant/booking_list/'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.booking_set.all()

Comment: when I press delete it returns to the booking_list view just fine... when I click amend, it does not go anywhere....no errors!

Comment: I click amend in user_booking.html it takes me to amend_booking.html and asks if I am sure I want to amend booking. When I click amend....nothing happens.

Comment: @Rp_Web Try to change the code of `amend_booking.html` to:`<form method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {{ form.as_p }} 
    <input type="submit" value="Save"> 
</form> `. Don' t change/remove the value `submit`

Comment: Wow...amazing!!! Thank you so much it has worked. Brilliant support Thank you.